# MVC JSON object with array not set properly

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am making a tool in which one can get a Quotation throw javascript and then send himself that quotation. The making of the quotation is going fine but when sending the email, the quotation data is corrupt.
The data in the `Quotation` object is fine except for the `Options` array. When sending 3 array items the `Options` array holds 3 items except for their **names are null and the price is 0**.

The quotation is send to ASP.NET MVC 3 using `jQuery.post`.

Quotation object in C# looks like:

```
public class Quotation
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal BasePrice { get; set; }
    public decimal SendPrice { get; set; }
    public Option[] Options { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
}
public class Option
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

The Action Method looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Offerte(Models.Quotation quotation)
{
    //
}
```

The jQuery looks like:

```
$.post(baseUrl + "/api/Offerte/", jsonContent, function (data) {
    alert(data.Message);
});
```

The jsonContent object looks like:

```
{
    "Options":[
        {
            "Name":"Extra pagina's (16)",
            "Price":40
        },
        {
            "Name":"Papier Keuze",
            "Price":30
        },
        {
            "Name":"Omslag",
            "Price":29.950000000000003
        }
    ],
    "Amount":"5",
    "BasePrice":99.96000000000001,
    "SubTotal":199.91000000000003,
    "SendPrice":0,
    "Discount":19.991,
    "TotalPrice":179.91900000000004,
    "Email":"someone@example.com"
}
```

Does anyone know why the array is not set properly?

---

**EDIT**
If I add this debug code to the controller:

```
using (var writer = System.IO.File.CreateText(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/debug.txt")))
{
    writer.AutoFlush = true;

    foreach (var key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(key + ": " + Request.Form[key]);
    }
}
```

> Options[0][Name]: Extra pagina's (52)
>   Options[0][Price]: 156
>   Options[1][Name]: Papier Keuze
>   Options[1][Price]: 68.4
>   Options[2][Name]: Omslag
>   Options[2][Price]: 41.94
>   Amount: 6
>   BasePrice: 149.91899999999998
>   SubTotal: 416.25899999999996
>   SendPrice: 0
>   Discount: 45.78848999999999
>   TotalPrice: 370.47051
>   Email: someone@example.com

This means that the data does get to the controller but the Options still doesn't get set right. And I don't want an easy fix that I parse it myself afterwards, I want to know the correct way to handle it so MVC will take care of it.

Comment: "The quotation is send to ASP.NET MVC 3 using jQuery.post." why you have this restriction? Can you use `jQuery.ajax` instead?

Comment: Looks like in your Quotation class, you're defining the options array to hold options rather than objects.

Comment: Or you need to override the set function to parse each option object and specifically set each property of the Option objects.

Comment: @nemesv not a restriction, just a choice.

Comment: @Derek That seems to be the problem. They are not parsed good. But do you know how to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know C# syntax, but I'm sure a quick google search will give u the answers u need.

Comment: @Derek Unfortunately it does not. The mvc framework auto parses it and I do not know how to tap into the parser. If I could tap into the parser I would be able to "help" the parser.

Comment: @SynerCoder What happens if you change Options from `Option[]` to `List<Option>`? I have had issues with binding to array properties in the past, so try that and see if we can eliminate that as a problem.

Comment: @HackedByChinese I tried it with an even more basic type: `IEnumerable<Option>` didn't work either. Same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send JSON data to an ASP.NET MVC controller action and you want the model  binding work currently (e.g. binding collections on your model) you need to specify the contentType as `"aplication/json"`.

Because with the `$.post` you are not able to specify the contentType you need to use `$.ajax` and you also need to `JSON.stringify` your data:

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + "/api/Offerte/",
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonContent),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.Message);
    }
});
```

Comment: The fourth parameter if the .post() function is the content type. Using 'json' for that value would work

Comment: @Derek no the fourth parameter is the [data type](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/): `dataType
Type: String
The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).` which is different than then contentType.

Comment: @nemesv The client side is not the problem. The problem is how MVC parses/reads the data. As you can read in my question everything is received fine **EXCEPT** for the array.

Comment: @SynerCoder have you tried out my solution? I know that only the array is not working but MVC handles the collections differently that is why the rest is working already. If still not working you can try with `data: JSON.stringify(jsonContent),`

Comment: @nemesv I just did to be sure, but not working. Like I said the clientside is not the problem. It is how MVC parses the data.

Comment: @SynerCoder have you tried with `$.ajax` and `data: JSON.stringify(jsonContent)`? In a newly created MVC project your code together with my suggested solution works just fine. All the options data is filled in.